# What are the equal sides lengths of an isosceles triangle with base 16?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> What are the equal sides lengths of an isosceles triangle with base 16?

I feel like there is some information missing.  Is there a way to do this problem?

#### Context

I teach math and someone is asking me this over the internet;  I feel you would need to know an angle, height, perimeter, or area to figure this out.

Comment: Yes you'd need to know an angle

Comment: Or an altitude or area or circumradius or some other property that distinguishes a $16,9,9$ triangle from a $16,10,10$ triangle.

Comment: Thank you!  I teach math and someone is asking me this over the internet and I feel you would need to know an angle, height, perimeter, or area to figure this out.  Thanks for confirming I'm not crazy. :)

Comment: One thing you can say is that the length of each leg has to exceed $8$ in order to satisfy the Triangle Inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you intend the base to be not one of the sides of equal length.

Each of the remaining side lengths should be greater than 8 units long for a triangle to exist.  Other than that, there are an infinite number of possible solutions if no angle in the triangle is specified.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the original post, the additional information need not be an angle.  It could be a height, perimeter, area, or something else.